# Hover over image won't appear when site is live

Tags: css, hover

So when working with this site locally on my computer the hover over image works perfect.  However, when I put the site up on a server then the image doesn't appear.

I'm referring to the links with the grey background image.  I've provided the css specifically for the Contact us link.

http://bankruptcyimmigrationlaw.com/NEWSTARTLAW/Home.html

```
...

#Contact_us li:first-child a {
padding:9px 5px 15px 30px;
margin-top:25px;
background-image:url(../images/DefaultNavBg.png);
background-position:-30px -15px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:76px;
width:350px;
border-bottom:none;
text-decoration:none;
}

#Contact_us li:first-child a:hover {
padding:9px 5px 0px 15px;
margin-top:25px;
background-image:url(../images/CurrentNavBg.png);
background-position:-30px -15px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:76px;
width:350px;
border-bottom:none;
cursor:pointer;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting 404s for `http://bankruptcyimmigrationlaw.com/NEWSTARTLAW/images/CurrentNavBg.png`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your images isn't where you think it is, I'm getting 404.  It could be that you didn't upload it, or if your testing on Windows and deploying to *Nix it could be an issue with the case of the file (or directory) name.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't send the image to the server:

http://bankruptcyimmigrationlaw.com/NEWSTARTLAW/images/CurrentNavBg.png

returns 404

Tip: Using webrowser with some king of `inspector` - for an example `Chrome` with build-in inspector or `Firefox` + `Firebug` is best friend of every webmaster, webdevloper, webdesigner, etc.

**Edit**

Try to avoid `CaseMixing` in all your file names and paths. This is very reason of mistakes and bugs, so using same variation of lower case is definitely better.

My favourite notation `is_lower_case_underscored.jpg`,

using hypens is other recommended way, however it can be reason of mistakes when creating filenames with JavaScript as the hypen can be recognized as `minus operator` by accident.

Comment: Thx it was just a matter of capitalization.  For some reason it was CurrentNavBg.png in the css and the image was labeled CurrentNavbg.png